# Lock a folder so that user can't access but software can

Tags: windows-7, security, password-protection, lock

i have a situation here
i need to lock a folder (password protect) so that user can't access it without password application/software can access that folder.. :)

What i can now:
i know i can lock the folder using folder security properties tab. but the problem is if i lock that folder then software also can't access that folder. And also users use the same user account :(

so, i am looking for a way where i can password protect a folder so software can access that folder as regular folder but user without password can't access

hope that makes sense

best regards

Comment: This may answer your question regarding password protecting a folder: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/password-protect-files-folders#1TC=windows-7 Having said that, you could run your program under different credentials by writing a wrapper in, say, AutoIt, which passes the necessary credentials. You then disallow access for those users who don't need it, but allow the one running the program to have complete access. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This makes no sense.  Applications launched by a user can only access files the user itself can access.